# Div bigger then Content after centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After 1 hour of try and error and searching for problems like this, i try to get an answer here.

I want to include a bootstrap Nav-Bar into a Div. I centered the Nav-Bar, but now my Div is higher then the content. This problem is only available when the Nav-Bar is centered. If i let it float left, the space below the Nav-Bar isnt there.

i think it has something to do with the

```
ul{     
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thats what i have.

[Menu centered but **to much space below**](http://bit.ly/1dJXjNR)

Thats what i want, just centered:

[No space below **but centered left**](http://bit.ly/1BgEkWh)

hope you can help me :)

Comment: `#header {height:50px;}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `vertical-align: top;` in `.nav` hope this will solve your issue

**[updated working code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJMvjr)**

Comment: Yeah nice. Thats exactly what i needed, because i dont want to give the header a hight :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding height to the header: `#header {height:50px;}`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpvJRo

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/m28mzk11/1/

```
.nav-pills{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: /* Set your width here */
}

nav ul li {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This should center your text and make your li width being automaticly calculated

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple corrections in your code.

```
.nav-pills
{
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-pills li
 {
   display: inline-block;
   *display: inline;zoom: 1;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
 }
```

*display: inline;zoom: 1

is used because to even apply for IE7 browser because IE7 does not support display: inline-block